# Global "Loading" notification with ASP.NET MVC Ajax calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm interested in providing a general "I'm making an ajax call" notification ... similar to how most of google's services have a little red loading notification when it's busy making a call.  Is there a way of globally tapping into some event that I can use to show/hide that notification if there is an active call?

We're not using the jQuery ajax apis, we're using the MVC Ajax stuff ... such as Ajax.BeginForm, or Ajax.ActionLink.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why the previous answer was accepted, but you can just use the **LoadingElementId** parameter in your **AjaxOptions**, by specifying an ID of an element in your page which has its *display* CSS property set to *none*.

```
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "somebox", LoadingElementId = "status-waiting" }
```

MVC will do the rest of the work for you: when the request initiates, the DIV will be shown, and once it completes - hidden again. All you have to do is style the box (position it, provide 'loading' image, etc.).

Comment: It was accepted because you hadn't written this answer yet ;-) thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using JQuery to [make AJAX](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) calls you can use something among the lines:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'url_to_send_ajax_request_to',
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        jQuery('#id_of_some_div_that_contains_loading_text').show();
    },    
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        jQuery('#id_of_some_div_that_contains_loading_text').hide();
    }
});
```

The *beforeSend* handler can be used to show a hidden div containing your loading text or image while *complete* handler will be used to hide it (no matter whether the call succeeds or not).

Or if you want to set it up globally for all AJAX requests you can use the [ajaxSetup](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup) function:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        jQuery('#id_of_some_div_that_contains_loading_text').show();
    },    
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        jQuery('#id_of_some_div_that_contains_loading_text').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: We use the jQuery ajax in just one instance ... all the other functionalities are using the MVC ajax libs.  For example Ajax.BeginForm( ...

Comment: I don't know much about AJAX but shouldn't "XMLHttpReques" have a "t" on the end?  It seems you have it without a "t" in both of the "beforeSend" attributes you have specified.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted when the question says "We're not using the jQuery ajax apis"?